# Is it possible to extend from function type? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, operator-overloading

As an exercise for myself, I'm trying to write a class in Python that works similarly to events in C#.

Here are the two main functions in the class (__subs is a list):

```
class Event (object):
    def __iadd__ (self, other):
        if not callable(other):
            raise ValueError("%s must be callable" % other)
        self.__subs.append(other)
        return self

    def __add__ (self, other):
        if not callable(other):
            raise ValueError("%s must be callable" % other)
        new = Event()
        new.__subs = [f for f in self.__subs]
        new.__subs.append(other)
        return new

    def __call__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        for func in self.__subs:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
```

this allows the following syntaxes:

```
e1 = Event()
e1 += afunction
e2 += another
e1 (arg1, arg = val) # afunction and another will be called with arg1 and val

e2 = Event() + afunction + another
e2 (arg1, arg = val)

(Event() + afunction + another) (arg1, arg = val)
```

However, I would like to simplify the last two to just be something like this

```
e = afunction + another
e (arg1, arg = val)

(afunction + another) (arg1, arg = val)
```

I tried doing this, but I get the error "TypeError: 'function' is not an acceptable base type"

```
class function (FunctionType):
    def __add__ (self, other):
        return Event() + self + other
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly subclass functions, no. At most you could create a wrapper class, one that passes on all attribute access to the underlying function.

To support calling, give the wrapper class a [`object.__call__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__):

```
class FunctionWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._func, attr)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._func(*args, **kwargs)

    # additional methods
```

You can 'paint' this onto function declarations with the decorator syntax even:

```
@FunctionWrapper
def foo(): pass
```

Demo:

```
>>> @FunctionWrapper
... def foo():
...     return 'bar'
... 
>>> foo
<__main__.FunctionWrapper object at 0x102544850>
>>> foo()
'bar'
>>> foo.__name__
'foo'
>>> foo.__code__
<code object foo at 0x1026cb730, file "<stdin>", line 1>
```

Comment: So `@FunctionWrapper` basically does `foo = FunctionWrapper(foo)` after the definition?

Comment: @TangibleLight: exactly, got it in one. See the [original proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#motivation).